# Possible to import module to ChromeWorker

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I was trying to import osfile.jsm to my ChromeWorker so I can use it to get the os. Like if I do `OS.Constants.Sys.Name` it tells me `WINNT` or `Darwin` or etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use `OS.Constants` in a ChromeWorker without importing anything.

Comment: Too cool! What about the file i/o of os.file? and promises? do i need to import promise.jsm would things silently fail?

Comment: FYI to all wondeirng about this: From ChromeWorker context, OS.File stuff does not return promises, it's synchronus. Thanks to Yoric for that input on irc. Super cool stuff!